# "pyinstaller" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

Estoy tratando de crear el archivo .exe de mi programa desarrollado en Python usando Tkinter, instale por medio de PIP  PyInstaller pero no he podido crear mi archivo, al momento de utilizar la sentencia:

```
pyinstaller --onefile index.py
```

me muestra el siguiente error:

> ```
> "pyinstaller" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
> ```

debo aclarar también que esta sentencia la he utilizado desde la ruta donde se encuentran los scrips de PyInstaller y también en la ruta donde se encuentra mi archivo.

Utilizo Windows 10, python 3.7, tkinter y PyInstaller 3.6

Comment: Si esta instalado y si lo puedo importar sin problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se produce porque el ejecutable no está en el directorio de trabajo actual ni está agregado al PATH. Tienes varias opciones:

### Agregar la ruta del script al PATH

La el ejecutable de pyinstaller se aloja en `PythonXY\Scripts`, en tu caso `Python37\Scripts`. La ruta generalmente es en Windows:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts
```

### Ejecutar pyinstaller.exe proveyendo la ruta adecuada al ejecutable

- Puedes abrir la terminal en la ruta antes mencionada, dónde debe estar pyinstaller.exe (en el explorador de archivos abres el directorio Scripts y en al barra de direcciones introduces cmd y pulsas <kbd>Enter</kbd>) y luego simplemente usar:

  ```
  pyinstaller --onefile index.py
  ```
- Puedes usar `cd` para colocar el directorio de trabajo de la consola en ese directorio y luego simplemente usar:

  ```
  pyinstaller --onefile index.py
  ```
- Puedes ejecutar directamente usando la ruta absoluta:

  ```
  C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller --onefile index.py `
  ```

> **Nota**: obviamente hay que cambiar `%USERNAME%` por el usuario de turno, si la ruta de instalación de Python no fuera esa, podemos obtenerla mediante `import sys; print(sys.executable)` en un intérprete interactivo o en un script.

### Lanzar PyInstaller directamente como módulo

```
py -3.7 -m PyInstaller --onefile index.py
```

Comment: Lanzar PyInstaller directamente como módulo
py -3.7 -m PyInstaller --onefile index.py Esto en donde tendria que hacerlo ?

Answer (score 0):

Personalmente, intenté con todo lo que dijo FJSevilla y solo me funcionó la de Lanzar PyInstaller como módulo. Encima es la más facil. Mil gracias!

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/347447)

Answer (score 0):

Solo puse:

```
py -m pip install pyinstaller
```

y me funcionó.

Comment: Gracias por responder. ¿Podrías añadir una breve descripción de qué es lo que este comando?